# How do I crop Jpeg image from/to a URL, Swift, MacOS

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I want to do a rectangular crop of a JPEG image. I have the following code that will create a duplicate image. It uses an NSImage. I do not know how to create a cropped image.

```
   func crop(index: Int)  {
        let croppedImageUrl = ...
        let imageUrl = ...

        // Create a cropped image.
        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: imageUrl)
        let image = NSImage(data: data!)
        let tiffRepresentation = (image?.tiffRepresentation)!
        let bitmap = NSBitmapImageRep(data: tiffRepresentation)
        let representation = bitmap?.representation(using: NSBitmapImageRep.FileType.jpeg, properties: [:])
        do {
            try representation?.write(to: croppedImageUrl, options: [.withoutOverwriting])
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Considering...
`let croppedCGImage = (image?.cgImage(forProposedRect: nil, context: nil, hints: nil)?.cropping(to: CGRect()))!`

`let croppedNSImage = NSImage(cgImage: croppedCGImage, size: NSSize())`

Answer (score -1):

Something like...

```
func crop(nsImage: NSImage,rect: CGRect) -> NSImage {  
    let cgImage = (nsImage?.cgImage(forProposedRect: nil, context: nil, hints: nil)?.cropping(to: rect))!

    let size = NSSize(width: rect.width, height: rect.height)
    return NSImage(cgImage: cgImage, size: size)
}
```

Sorry, not compiled this code fragment but general method worked in my code. Probably better done as an extension to NSImage, if that is possible.

Comment: This code only resizes the source image, not cropping it.